# Crawling a SalesForce site fully generated by JS with Screaming Frog only gets content on some pages

Tags: web-crawlers, javascript, ajax, screaming-frog

I'm trying to crawl a Salesforce-generated site. This site appears to be fully generated by Javascript (if you load the page with JS disabled only a white screen shows up). For instance, [Salesforce's own KB](https://help.salesforce.com/home) behaves this way.

Some of the pages come back as rendered and crawled, most come back as just blank. I'm unsure of if there's a way to get Screaming Frog to wait until page content loads on each article.

I currently have rendering set to "Javascript" which allows me to view some pages but not all.

Comment: You might need to increase the AJAX timeout (default is 5 seconds), which is how many seconds before a snapshot of the page is taken. More at https://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/crawl-javascript-seo/.

Comment: @Nick Sounds like an answer! Cheers!!

Comment: That is the risk you take rendering the page using JS. You can expect to have issues periodically using this method. IP is not a guaranteed delivery protocol. Placing all the burden on the client end means increased likely hood of failure. Just a warning. Cheers!!